# How do I show that functions converges in the measure?

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence

I have the following problem:

> Let $f,g,f_1,f_2,...,g_1,g_2,...$ be mesurable functions such that $$f_n\stackrel{\mu}{\rightarrow} f \,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,g_n\stackrel{\mu}{\rightarrow} g$$ and for all n $$|f_n(x)|\leq 1\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,|g_n(x)|\leq 1\,\,\,\text{for almost every x} $$Show that $$f_ng_n\stackrel{\mu}{\rightarrow}fg$$

I wanted to proof this in the following way:

**Proof**

We know the following points:

1. $f_n\stackrel{\mu}{\rightarrow} f\Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon>0\,\,\mu\left(\{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon\}\right)\rightarrow 0$
2. $g_n\stackrel{\mu}{\rightarrow} g\Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon>0\,\,\mu\left(\{x:|g_n(x)-g(x)|\geq \epsilon\}\right)\rightarrow 0$
3. $|g_n(x)|\leq 1\,\,\,\text{for almost every x}\Leftrightarrow \mu\left(\{x:|g_n(x)|>1\}\right)=0$
4. $|f_n(x)|\leq 1\,\,\,\text{for almost every x}\Leftrightarrow \mu\left(\{x:|f_n(x)|>1\}\right)=0$

We have also just proven in the previous exercise, that with this assumptions we have that $$|f(x)|\leq 1\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,|g(x)|\leq 1\,\,\,\text{for almost every x}$$

We want to show that forall $\epsilon >0$ we have $\mu\left(\{x:|f_n(x)g_n(x)-f(x)g(x)|\geq \epsilon\}\right)\rightarrow 0$. Let us write $$f_n(x)g_n(x)-f(x)g(x)=f_n(x)g_n(x)-f(x)g_n(x)+f(x)g_n(x)-f(x)g(x)$$ Then we get with the points from aboce that $$|f_n(x)g_n(x)-f(x)g(x)|\leq |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|g_n(x)-g(x)|$$

In my opinion I think that I'm not really far away since this looks similar to the points 1.,2. in the remark, so I think I only need to use them to conclude but I somehow don't see how I can do this so can I simply say that $\{x:|f_n(x)g_n(x)-f(x)g(x)|\geq \epsilon\}\subset \{x:|f_n(x)-f(x)|+|g_n(x)-g(x)|\geq \epsilon\}$ and then use the monotonicity of the measure and the above points to conclude?. Could someone give me a hint?

Thank you for your help

Comment: *Hint.* For $|f_n(x)-f(x)|+|g_n(x)-g(x)|\ge\epsilon$ to hold, at least one of the quantities $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ or $|g_n(x)-g(x)|$ must be at least $\epsilon/2$.

Comment: Yes this makes sense but can I then write $\{x:|f_n-f|+|g_n-g|\geq \epsilon\}=\{x:|f_n-f|\geq \epsilon/2\}\cup\{x:|g_n-g|\geq \epsilon'\}$ where $\epsilon/2+\epsilon'=\epsilon$ or how can I use this hint, because it makes sense

Comment: Use (sub-)additivity of measures, as you suggested. Both $\{|f_n-f|\ge\epsilon/2\}$ and $\{|g_n-g|\ge\epsilon\}$ have vanishing measures.

Comment: ah perfect thank you!